# Can vim open a shared folder in another local machine and edit files?

Tags: vim

I googled and found that vim scp://server/path/to/file can edit a single file. But I could not use it to open a folder.

Comment: Why don't you just use ssh to run vim ? E.g. `ssh user@server vim ...`

Comment: I want to use my own vim configuration and don't want to modify server's configuration. I am new to vim.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `/` at the end of your url:

```
vim scp://server/path/to/
```

Comment: Maybe, but it's your only solution. `:help netrw`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [vim's network-oriented file transfers](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Edit_remote_files_locally_via_SCP/RCP/FTP).
According to [the documentation](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1075), it *"supports remote and local directory browsing, and supports  editing files across the network using a variety of methods"*.